# Trying to pull checkbox status back from database and display it on form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I am in the process of creating a simple web application to track visitors to a church.  I have created the form that is used to add visitors to the database and am using several check boxes for yes/no answers as per below which works perfectly and enters either yes or no to the db depending on the status of the checkbox.

```
<input type="hidden" value="no" name="relationship">
<input type="checkbox" value ="yes" name="relationship">
```

Now, here is where I'm having an issue.  I have been asked to add in the ability for the administrator to be able to update the records using a similar form layout.  I have managed to get the text boxes to pull the existing from the database by using code like below.

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo $visitor_data['first_name'], ' '; ?>">
```

However, how can I do the same for a checkbox?  I have searched here and can not find anything about it.  Greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: Create a checkbox and add `checked` to it if the value from the db is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to check the value and set your checkbox to `checked`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="relationship" <?php if ($visitor_data['checkbox'] == "yes"){ echo 'checked="checked"'} ?>/>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for and worked a treat.